# How can I handle either an array or a single object with the same MVC controller method?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ActionResult method that accepts a list as an argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod (List<ClassA> json)
{
   ...
}
```

This binds the json string coming in to a generic list of ClassA objects, which are populated.

The problem is sometimes the json coming in is just a single json object and not an array of json objects.

Is there some way to preempt this so I can bind directly to ClassA vs List?  Or is there some other technique I can use?

Here is how the JSON is being sent (as an array):

```
var myjsonarray = [{
  "ID": "1",
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Doe",
}, {
  "ID": "2",
  "FirstName": "Jane",
  "LastName": "Doe",
}];

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 url: "/Home/MyPage",
 data: JSON.stringify(myjsonarray),
 dataType: 'json'
});
```

The above processes fine.  This also works:

```
var myjsonarray = [{
  "ID": "1",
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Doe",
}];
```

But when I send as a single object not wrapped in an array:

```
var myjsonarray = {
  "ID": "1",
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Doe",
};
```

My ActionResult method parameter is null:

```
json == null
```

Comment: can you show the necessary code ?

Comment: I've updated the post.  Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: **The problem is sometimes the json coming in is just a single json object and not an array of json objects.** Can you show the code how we are passing the json to server?

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't have control over the client code, correct?

Comment: The client yes but not the source (sender).  My ajax example above is just for my own testing.  The MVC app is mine.  The sender app is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it is not clear from your question, it seems from the comments on other answers that you do not have control over the client code that is sending you this JSON.  (If you did, the simplest solution is to wrap your single object in an array before sending it, as others have already suggested.)

It would be great if MVC allowed us to add a method overload in the controller to handle this situation, e.g.:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod (List<ClassA> list)
{
   ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod (ClassA single)
{
   ...
}
```

While this compiles fine, it unfortunately results in a `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException` when you hit the method at run time.

So, it looks like you will need to create a custom [IModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder.aspx) to solve the problem.  While I have not implemented a custom model binder before, I took it as a challenge and came up with the following.  You'll obviously have to tweak it for your own needs, but it is seems to work with your example.

Here is the code:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        IValueProvider provider = bindingContext.ValueProvider;

        // Check whether we have a list or a single object.  If we have a list
        // then all the properties will be prefixed with an index in square brackets.
        if (provider.ContainsPrefix("[0]"))
        {
            // We have a list.  Since that is what the controller method is 
            // expecting, just use the default model binder to do the work for us.
            return ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
        else
        {
            // We have a single object.
            // Bind it manually and return it in a list.
            ClassA a = new ClassA();
            a.ID = GetValue<int>(provider, "ID");
            a.FirstName = GetValue<string>(provider, "FirstName");
            a.LastName = GetValue<string>(provider, "LastName");
            return new List<ClassA> { a };
        }
    }

    private T GetValue<T>(IValueProvider provider, string key)
    {
        ValueProviderResult result = provider.GetValue(key);
        return (result != null ? (T)result.ConvertTo(typeof(T)) : default(T));
    }
}
```

To insert this custom binder into the MVC pipeline, add this line to the `Application_Start()` method in your `Global.asax.cs`.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(List<ClassA>), new CustomModelBinder());
```

Now, clearly this is not a generic solution; it is tailored specifically to handle `ClassA` and nothing else.  I have to believe it is possible to make a generic solution that would handle this "single-or-list" situation for a list of any type, but that is much more complicated and beyond the scope of this answer.  To do so you would likely also need to create a custom [`IModelBinderProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinderprovider.aspx).  If you want to take it to that level, you'll need to investigate that on your own.  Here is an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) that might give you some more insight into how binding works behind the scenes.

Comment: Hey Brian, this is definitely working. I do have to use "json[0]" and "json.ID" prefix for the fields.  It will need to be made more generic and I'm using the link you provided to look further into it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'd better leave your API unchanged and add this logic to your JavaScript code to always pass in the same type as a list. It will be easy for maintenance and test.

```
if(typeof(myjsonarray) === 'object'){
    myjsonarray = [myjsonarray];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you accept collection so you need to send collection via array in js:

You can create array even for one element

You can create another action method to accept element not array

HTH

Comment: With a different name correct?  I provider is sender the data and will look for only one method.

Comment: You can use with the same name and mvc binder automatically selects right one

Comment: @syned It seems this is not the case-- I get a `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException`.